# Compare tensor of unsigned int to python int

Tags: python, tensorflow, int, equality

I want to compare a TensorFlow tensor of unsigned int e.g. `tf.uint32` to the python integer `1`. How do I do that? All the following fail

```py
ones = tf.ones((2, 3), dtype=tf.uint32)
ones == 1
ones == [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
ones == tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.uint32)
ones == tf.ones((2, 3), dtype=tf.uint32)  # ?!!! I'm surprised this doesn't work
ones == tf.constant([[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], dtype=tf.uint32)
```

with the cryptic

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Could not find valid device for node.
Node:{{node Equal}}
All kernels registered for op Equal :
  device='XLA_GPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_UINT8, DT_INT16, ..., DT_QUINT8, DT_QINT32, DT_BFLOAT16, DT_COMPLEX128, DT_HALF]
  device='XLA_CPU_JIT'; T in [DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_UINT8, DT_INT16, ..., DT_QUINT8, DT_QINT32, DT_BFLOAT16, DT_COMPLEX128, DT_HALF]
  device='XLA_GPU_JIT'; T in [DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_UINT8, DT_INT16, ..., DT_QUINT8, DT_QINT32, DT_BFLOAT16, DT_COMPLEX128, DT_HALF]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_BOOL]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_COMPLEX128]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_COMPLEX64]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_INT64]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_INT16]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_INT8]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_INT32]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_UINT8]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_HALF]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_BOOL]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_STRING]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_COMPLEX128]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_COMPLEX64]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT64]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT32]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_BFLOAT16]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT16]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT8]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_UINT8]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_HALF]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='XLA_CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_UINT8, DT_INT16, ..., DT_QUINT8, DT_QINT32, DT_BFLOAT16, DT_COMPLEX128, DT_HALF]
 [Op:Equal]
```

while with `tf.int32` it works fine

```py
>>> tf.ones((2, 3), dtype=tf.int32) == 1
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 3), dtype=bool, numpy=
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]])>
```

Comment: Do you really need uint32, you can always cast and compare? Or do you just want to know the source of the error?

Comment: i'd like to use `uint32` for the original tensor. I'm happy to `cast`. In fact that answers my question, thanks. But I'm now also curious why none of those comparisons work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare with `uint8`. For example, the following snippet gives correct output:

```
ones = tf.ones((2, 3), dtype=tf.uint8)
ones == 1
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 3), dtype=bool, numpy=
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]])>
```

You can also cast for any unsupported dtypes.

```
ones = tf.ones((2, 3), dtype = tf.uint32)
ones_c = tf.cast(ones, dtype = tf.int32)
ones_c == 1
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 3), dtype=bool, numpy=
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]])>
```

As it seems like a bug, here's a GitHub issue regarding the behavior (to track):

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39457

**Update:** Now, you can use `tf-nightly` to compare `uint16` and `uint32`.

https://pypi.org/project/tf-nightly-gpu/